# SQL : Subquery returned more than 1 value

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I am working on Saas based project. In that, they provide to write SQL query as subquery in Where clause to fetch matching data of Table. My Issue is, I can only write SubQuery in Where Clause so I cannot modify outerquery.

```
select 
    T.TransactionID, T.DateCreated 
from 
    xt2010_PARTICIPANTS T -- **I cannot modify this**
where --**I can modify whatever inside the Where Clause**
    ((ParticipantID in (select 
                            case 
                               when dbo.UserIsInRole({CurrentRole}, "1") 
                                  then (select ParticipantID
                                        from xt2010_PARTICIPANTS p
                                        where p.DivisionID = T.[DivisionID]
                                          and p.ParticipantID = T.[ParticipantID]) 
                                  else (select p.ParticipantID 
                                        from xt2010_PARTICIPANTS p 
                                        inner join xt2010_PARTICIPANTSUPPORT ps on p.ParticipantID = ps.ParticipantID
                                        inner join xt2010_CONTACTS c on c.DivisionID = p.DivisionID
                                                                     and c.ContactID = ps.ContactID
                                        where c.UserID = 'John1.Abraham_1@cared_t')
                            end))
)
```

I can change only subquery of `Where` clause of participant table.

I am getting error:

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

Comment: The error is telling you the problem. What about it don't you understand? Then we can try to elaborate, however, it isn't one of the more "cryptic" error messages from SQL Server.

Comment: Your subquery **needs** to return 1 row. Considering we don't know you're data model, nor do we have any sample data, expected results and the logic behind those result, we can't tell you what the correct solution is.

Comment: You have two subqueries: we can't tell which one has the problem.  Do you know which it is?

Comment: They actually have three, @AnnL., just the first won't be producing the error as it's used in an `IN`. :)

Comment: SELECT p.ParticipantID FROM xt2010_PARTICIPANTS p INNER JOIN
xt2010_PARTICIPANTSUPPORT ps ON 
p.ParticipantID = ps.ParticipantID
INNER JOIN xt2010_CONTACTS c ON c.DivisionID = p.DivisionID
AND c.ContactID = ps.ContactID
Where c.UserID = 'John1.Abraham_1@cared_t'

which is actually executing right now

Answer (score 1):

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

You have 2 of those:

```sql
SELECT ParticipantID
  FROM xt2010_PARTICIPANTS p
 WHERE p.DivisionID = T.[DivisionID]
   AND p.ParticipantID = T.[ParticipantID]

SELECT p.ParticipantID
FROM xt2010_PARTICIPANTS p
INNER JOIN xt2010_PARTICIPANTSUPPORT ps ON p.ParticipantID = ps.ParticipantID
INNER JOIN xt2010_CONTACTS c ON c.DivisionID = p.DivisionID
                             AND c.ContactID = ps.ContactID
WHERE c.UserID = 'John1.Abraham_1@cared_t'
```

One (or both) of these queries return more than one row.

You have 2 choices. The first is to make sure they only return 1 row, e.g. by tightening the conditions, or by adding e.g. `DISTINCT` or `MAX(...)`.

However, since they are using in an `IN` clause, which supports multiple rows, a better solution is to rewrite the query so the subqueries are not used as expressions.

Your main expression is:

```sql
WHERE ParticipantID IN (
         SELECT CASE WHEN dbo.UserIsInRole({CurrentRole}, "1") THEN
                   (...) 
                ELSE
                   (...)
                END
      )
```

The `UserIsInRole()` expression is unrelated to the data, and is used to choose which subquery to execute, so flip the `IN` and `CASE` clauses:

```sql
WHERE CASE WHEN dbo.UserIsInRole({CurrentRole}, "1") THEN
         CASE WHEN ParticipantID IN (...) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
      ELSE
         CASE WHEN ParticipantID IN (...) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
      END = 1
```

The query will now support multiple rows in the subqueries:

```sql
WHERE CASE WHEN dbo.UserIsInRole({CurrentRole}, "1")
      THEN CASE WHEN ParticipantID IN (
              SELECT ParticipantID
                FROM xt2010_PARTICIPANTS p
               WHERE p.DivisionID = T.[DivisionID]
                 AND p.ParticipantID = T.[ParticipantID]
           ) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
      ELSE CASE WHEN ParticipantID IN (
              SELECT p.ParticipantID
                FROM xt2010_PARTICIPANTS p
               INNER JOIN xt2010_PARTICIPANTSUPPORT ps ON p.ParticipantID = ps.ParticipantID
               INNER JOIN xt2010_CONTACTS c ON c.DivisionID = p.DivisionID
                                           AND c.ContactID = ps.ContactID
               WHERE c.UserID = 'John1.Abraham_1@cared_t'
           ) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
      END = 1
```

Comment: Your `THEN` makes no sense. A `CASE` expression returns a Scalar value, not a Boolean result. This will generate a different error.

Comment: @Larnu Dang, works on PostgreSQL and MySQL, but not on Oracle and SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like you may have some confusion about how the `IN` and `CASE` statements can be used.

After studying your query for a bit, I'm going to assume that what you are trying to express is

> Return records from T when T.ParticipantID is in [first subquery] and
> user is in [current role], or when T.ParticipantID is in [second
> subquery] and user is NOT in [current role].

You need to structure this differently.

```
WHERE (
   dbo.UserIsInRole({CurrentRole}, "1")
   and T.ParticipantID in 
       (SELECT ParticipantID
        FROM xt2010_PARTICIPANTS p
        WHERE p.DivisionID = T.[DivisionID]
        AND  p.ParticipantID = T.[ParticipantID]) 
   )
   or 
   (
      not dbo.UserIsInRole({CurrentRole}, "1")
      and T.ParticipantID in (
          SELECT p.ParticipantID 
          FROM   xt2010_PARTICIPANTS p 
            INNER JOIN
                 xt2010_PARTICIPANTSUPPORT ps 
                   ON p.ParticipantID = ps.ParticipantID
            INNER JOIN 
                 xt2010_CONTACTS c 
                   ON c.DivisionID = p.DivisionID
                   AND c.ContactID = ps.ContactID
          Where c.UserID = 'John1.Abraham_1@cared_t')
   )
```

Having laid it out like this, I think your first subquery is unnecessary: you're querying the same table as your main query table, and matching on the same keys!  But I don't truly know what you're attempting to do.